# sharing computation between repeat control data-binding and row property

Tags: java, xpages

For an xp:repeat control I compute the data-binding via a managed bean which contains a list of java objects in it. e.g.

```
employeeBean.loadList(key);
return employeeBean.profiles;
```

the first line will set the profiles field on the bean which will contain an arraylist with profile objects.

In some cases the customer does not want to have a pager control so I calculate the number of rows as followed:

```
employeeBean.loadList(key);
var coll = employeeBean.profiles;
return coll.length;
```

I notice I am calling the same method two times while I have the data already in the first call.

How can I share the data between the data-binding computation and the row property computation?

Comment: Where is this code placed? In the java bean or in the xsp source? Please provide more source code, both java and xsp.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Everything depends on `loadList()` implementation. Make it optimal to be called many times and you are fine. Just hold your list in some internal property of the bean and use cache:

```
if (property == null) {
  property = getListData();
}
return property;
```

Work with scope, `request` or `view` should be fine. In case your list contains Domino native objects, stick to `request` only.